# Data approximation with maxLik library. NaNs produced

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a data approximation for `quakes` dataset, `stations` column. I'm following an example in the maxLik library documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maxLik/maxLik.pdf

```r
library(maxLik)
set.seed(1)
attach(quakes)

## log likelihood function.
## Note: param is a vector
llf <- function( param ) {
  mu <- param[ 1 ]
  sigma <- param[ 2 ]
  llValue <- dnorm(stations, mean=mu, sd=sigma, log=TRUE)
  return(sum(llValue))
}
## Estimate it.  Take standard normal as start values
ml <- maxLik( llf, start = c(mu=0, sigma=1) )
```

I'm getting `In dnorm(stations, mean = mu, sd = sigma, log = TRUE) : NaNs produced` warning. This happens because `sum(llValue)` returns negative values. As a result, the approximation is very bad. If I change the code to `return(abs(sum(llValue)))` the warning disappear and the ​approximation is a bit closer, but still very bad.

What I'm doing wrong? How to make an approximation for `quakes$stations` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the wrong distribution for llValue. I tried to approximate lognormal distribution using the normal distribution.

Stations from quakes dataset could be approximated with following function

```
library(maxLik)
attach(quakes)

llf_dlnorm <- function(param) {
  mu <- param[ 1 ]
  sigma <- param[ 2 ]
  llValue <- dlnorm(stations, mean=mu, sd=sigma, log=TRUE)
  return(sum(llValue))
}

ml_dlnorm <- maxLik(llf_dlnorm, start = c(mu=mean(stations), sigma=sd(stations)))

x<-seq(0, 150, by=0.01)
hist(stations, prob=T)
lines(x,dlnorm(x, ml_dlnorm$estimate[1], ml_dlnorm$estimate[2]), col="blue",lwd=2)
```